# How to combine SQL queries with count(*)?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to combine three below SQL queries and the result should be displayed with three columns(firstname,schoolname,locationname).

- select count(*) as firstname from StudentRecord
- select count(*) as schoolname from SchoolRecord
- select count(*) as locationname from LocationRecord

Could you please clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: count (*) as firstname sounds like a thinking error as count delivers a number (in your case simply the number of rows of the respective table). Why would you call it a name? Please add more information about the data with which you are dealing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Peter... I am new to sql.. i am basically a different tech guy.. not part of sql.. but had recently dealing with sql query.. i will correct it thanks..

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    (select count(*) from StudentRecord)  as firstname,
    (select count(*) from SchoolRecord)   as schoolname,
    (select count(*) from LocationRecord) as locationname 
from dual
```

As already noticed, a bit add column names. And table names...